# How to points Width and Height from LoadImage() in PowerPoint

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I am using LoadPicture method in my macro to load an jpg image. I want to know its width and height but the values that I get are not useful. I try to find a solution in some forums and I saw this solution:

```
Set oBmp = LoadPicture(FileName)
Hght = ScaleX(oBmp.Width, vbHimetric, vbPixels)
Wdth = ScaleY(oBmp.Height, vbHimetric, vbPixels)
```

The problem is that in powerpoint ScaleX and ScaleY are not working. At least in my powerpoint gives me the compile error: Method or data member not found.

I am also trying with this peace of code:

```
Dim myPic As IPictureDisp

Set myPic = LoadPicture("C:\dink_template\dinkFile\sizeimage.jpg")
Hght = myPic.height
wid = myPic.width
```

I check the image and his size in pixels are height = 132px and width= 338px but with that I am getting Height = 2794 and width 7154

How can I use the ScaleX/ScaleY in powerpoint? Or if I cannot use them how can pass the values to pixel?

Comment: Please provide the code for functions `ScaleX` and `ScaleY` if those are giving you trouble.  Otherwise, you can simply refer to `Hght = oBMP.Height` and `Wdth = oBMP.Width`.

Comment: in the example where I saw the those line weren't any functions ScaleX or ScaleY. I thought that it was a method that vba have. Here is thread where I saw it: http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?600083-RESOLVED-Get-size-(Width-Height)-of-LoadPicture()

Comment: Yes, I see that it is an available method, but you're not calling it as an object method, you're attempting to call it as a function.  If you are folloowing the example and using `oBMP As IPictureDisp`, this is not an option for you.

Comment: Maybe try to follow the [advice here](http://www.tek-tips.com/viewthread.cfm?qid=371590) -- you need to load the picture into a userform, etc., or to some object that has a `ScaleX` and `ScaleY` methods.

Comment: I cannot make it work... what kind of variable is Picture1? In the example doesn't appear what it is and the row Picture1.ScaleX Picture1.width, Picture1.ScaleMode, vbHimetric is giving me an "Object required" error. I try to set it as object but it didn't work as well. Sorry but I am not sure what I have to do.

Comment: My fault... I was meaning a jpg instead of png but still I am not getting the height in pixels. I will edit the question with a better explanation.

Comment: I think that the 132 and 338 values are pixels... at least that is what my computer says. You mean that 2794 and 7154 values are points? What I want is to pass from 2794 to 132... I though that was what ScaleX does. BTW Thanks for the patient that you are having with me, I really appreciated it.

Comment: I think ScaleX is a VB method, not a VBA method... http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa244168(v=vs.60).aspx

Comment: yes it seems... so I cannot use ScaleX :( Any idea to pass from what I am getting to pixels?

Comment: I am looking forward to listen it! :)

Comment: Try it out :) it seems to be working as expected for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was fairly tricky.  The dimensions you're receiving from the `.Width` and `.Height` property are actually `OLE_YSIZE_HMETRIC`/`OLE_XSIZE_HMETRIC`, which from what I can find out, are an increment of measurement representing 0.01mm.

I didn't initially see any easy workaround for this, (formula or at least a WinAPI function that would be helpful).

**This should work for most users who have normal/default screen resolution settings**

Function uses late-binding/does not require a reference to Publisher, although the library still needs to be available on user's machine.

```
Option Explicit
Sub Test()
    Dim filepath$
    filePath = "C:\image_file.JPG"
    MsgBox "Height = " & GetImageDimensions(filepath)(0) & vbNewLine & _
        "Width = " & GetImageDimensions(filepath)(1), vbOKOnly, "Dimensions"
End Sub

   Function GetImageDimensions(filepath) As Variant
    'Function returns an array of (Height, Width) from a specific image file path
    '
    Dim tmp(0 To 1) As Long
    Dim oPub As Object
    Set oPub = CreateObject("Publisher.Application")
    'returning picture.width in OLE_YSIZE_HIMETRIC/OLE_XSIZE_HIMETRIC
    ' these are representing 0.01 mm
    With LoadPicture(filepath)
    'Multiply by 0.01 to get dimension in millimeters, then
    ' use the MS Publisher functions to convert millimeters -> points -> pixels
        tmp(0) = 0.01 * oPub.PointsToPixels(oPub.MillimetersToPoints(.Height))
        tmp(1) = 0.01 * oPub.PointsToPixels(oPub.MillimetersToPoints(.Width))
    End With
    GetImageDimensions = tmp

    End Function
```

Here is a test case:

[image]

And here are the results:

[image]

**UPDATE FROM COMMENTS**

I get the following dimensions while debugging:

- `.Height` = 3493
- `.Width` = 8943

However, you indicate that you get 2794 and 7154, respectively.

**I can replicate your results when I change screen resolution (e.g., 125%). The method below should resolve that discrepancy.**

Attempting to use WinAPI to (hopefully) account for whatever discrepancy we're getting (pixel size, perhaps is different on your computer, which could cause this, although I'd expect the Publisher functions would account for this...)

**This function with WinAPI call *should* work for all users, regardless of resolution**

```
Function GetImageDimensions2(filePath As String) As Variant
'Function returns an array of (Height, Width) from a specific image file path
Dim tmp(0 To 1) As Long
'returning picture.width in OLE_YSIZE_HIMETRIC/OLE_XSIZE_HIMETRIC
' these are representing 0.01 mm
With LoadPicture(filePath)
    tmp(0) = .Height / 2540 * (1440 / TwipsPerPixelY())
    tmp(1) = .Width / 2540 * (1440 / TwipsPerPixelX()) 
End With
GetImageDimensions2 = tmp
End Function
```

And include these WinAPI calls in another module:

```
Declare Function GetDC Lib "user32" (ByVal hwnd As Long) As Long
Declare Function ReleaseDC Lib "user32" (ByVal hwnd As Long, _
  ByVal hdc As Long) As Long
Declare Function GetDeviceCaps Lib "gdi32" (ByVal hdc As Long, _
  ByVal nIndex As Long) As Long

Const HWND_DESKTOP As Long = 0
Const LOGPIXELSX As Long = 88
Const LOGPIXELSY As Long = 90

'--------------------------------------------------
Function TwipsPerPixelX() As Single
'--------------------------------------------------
'Returns the width of a pixel, in twips.
'--------------------------------------------------
  Dim lngDC As Long
  lngDC = GetDC(HWND_DESKTOP)
  TwipsPerPixelX = 1440& / GetDeviceCaps(lngDC, LOGPIXELSX)
  ReleaseDC HWND_DESKTOP, lngDC
End Function

'--------------------------------------------------
Function TwipsPerPixelY() As Single
'--------------------------------------------------
'Returns the height of a pixel, in twips.
'--------------------------------------------------
  Dim lngDC As Long
  lngDC = GetDC(HWND_DESKTOP)
  TwipsPerPixelY = 1440& / GetDeviceCaps(lngDC, LOGPIXELSY)
  ReleaseDC HWND_DESKTOP, lngDC
End Function
```

Comment: Dam... it is not working for me :( have an image with size 338x132 and the values that I am getting are 270x106

Comment: Any chance you can upload the picture to imgur.com and send me a link?

Comment: And I have to say that I am using Windows 8 and office 365. Also that I only found Microsoft Publisher 15.0 Object Library. Hope it will help

Comment: Hmmmmm your image is scaled down for some reason. I am pretty much stumped on this, other than building in a correction factor, which will work for *this* time, but I am not sure how reliable it is in the long-run, because I don't understand why the values will be different for you.

Comment: yes is really weird because I check the relation between the real size and the one that I get and it is around 1.25 but is not always the same. Sometimes is 1.245 other times 1.251 others 1.249... but is not exactly the same... Thanks anyway for your help!!

Comment: well the discrepancy between 1.245/1.251/1.249/etc. is a rounding issue with VB's binary math, so that makes sense.

Comment: Try using a correction factor of 1.25  for now (see revision above).  I don't *like* that solution, but unless we can figure out why your computer is returning different dimensions to the `.Height` and `.Width`, we have to make this assumption I think.

Comment: I tried in my old computer and there is working well... I don't know what is going on in mine. I will check first the size with an image that I know the dimensions to know the factor that I have to put since this macro is suppose to use in several computers.

Comment: I made one more update, although I'm not sure if that will work either, if your computer is for some reason returning the *wrong* dimensions (and it seems that is the case), I'm not sure if the WinAPI method can fix that.  I even tried sizing/resizing/saving picture thinking maybe that would cause a conflict, but that didn't.

Comment: I would be curious to know if your display setting might affect this.  Which of the settings are you using? http://imgur.com/Csu0FEg

Comment: I have medium set... 125%. This can affect? O_O

Comment: Im' not sure if it will affect it, but I will check.

Comment: Yes, that setting affects it!!! I changed my setting to 125% and logged off, when i return, I get the dimensions like 270/106 that you receive.
  My update using the WinAPI solution seems to be correct, no matter the screen resolution.

Comment: Yeeees the WinApi solution works!! I never could guess the screen could affect... Thanks you very much man with that it will perfectly go on all computer :)

Comment: I saw a few comments when I tried some creative search queries, that hinted screen resolution setting and DPI auto-scaling might be the cause, when certain conditions are met.  I'm glad that fixed it for you , this was a really interesting question :)